# How to seed code first with classes that implement each other as properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

Here is the 2 classes I desire to have in a site that has albums with songs, but I'm not sure how to do the seed method. I've been reading very extensively on the subject, but so far I have not found this situation. This would be easily solved by not having Album as a property, since I could seed the songs first, but I really want the Album property. In fact, if I could eliminate albumId and just have the Album property, that would be nice too, although I'm not sure how the foreign key relationship would be enforced without an albumId property.
I'm sure there is a simple answer but I'm surprised it's so hard to find an example of this. 
So here are my 2 desired classes:

```
public class Album
{
    public Album()
    {
        Songs = new List<Song>();
    }
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfTracks { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    public int SongId { get; set; }
    public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Composers { get; set; }
    public List<string> FeaturedArtists { get; set; }
    public List<string> Producers { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    public int? AlbumId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my incomplete seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(IQsLab.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Albums.AddOrUpdate(
          p => p.Artist,
          new Album { 
              Artist = "Linguistics",
              Name = "The Writes of Passage",
              NumberOfTracks = 17,
              ReleaseYear = 2007,
              AlbumId = 1,
              Songs = new List<Song>()
              {
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 1,
                      AlbumId = 1,
                      Album = ??????????????????????????????????????,
                      Name = "Glory",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      FeaturedArtists = new List<string>{
                          "Dj Solo",
                          "DJ Step 1"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 2,
                      Name = "Children of Atlantis",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 3,
                      Name = "On the Grind",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 4,
                      Name = "No Turnin Back",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      FeaturedArtists = new List<string>{
                          "Tassa"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 5,
                      Name = "How Many",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 6,
                      Name = "Have Faith",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 7,
                      Name = "Mozart's Finest",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      FeaturedArtists = new List<string>{
                          "Dj Solo",
                          "2Mex"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 8,
                      Name = "The Museum",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      },
                      FeaturedArtists = new List<string>{
                          "DJ 3rdi"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 9,
                      Name = "Broken Tongues",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Anno Domini"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Anno Domini"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 10,
                      Name = "Politics",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Kasper"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Kasper"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 11,
                      Name = "The Music Is Ours",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 12,
                      Name = "It's Us",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      FeaturedArtists = new List<string>{
                          "2Mex"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 13,
                      Name = "Where Did Hip-hop Go?",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Dan Kemp"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 14,
                      Name = "Tha Realness",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Kasper"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Kasper"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 15,
                      Name = "How To Make It",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 16,
                      Name = "A Warrior's Ballad",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      FeaturedArtists = new List<string>{
                          "Tassa"
                      }
                  },
                  new Song{
                      TrackNumber = 17,
                      Name = "Multiple Choice",
                      Composers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      },
                      Producers = new List<string>(){
                          "Bobby Ruckuss"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
        );

    }
```

So basically, how can I set Album = thisAlbumImCreatingRightNow, ?

Comment: EF should just insert an `AlbumId` and that's all what he need. Try to query `Songs` and check if EF populated `Album` property.

Comment: Thank you, I know that is a solution, but it's a solution I don't like. If it's the only solution available, so be it. I'll just delete the Album property or not set it in the seed method, but I'm hoping someone has a creative way that I can seed this the way I want and have that Album property as part of the the class, since it might come in handy later.

Comment: When materializing (retrieving entities from database) EF would place a correct reference at `Album`, so you can use it later

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you. I'm new to Code first, so I guess I'll just stop trying to set the Album property of each song and just use the albumid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to create your albums and songs,set the relations between them and call save changes. The `DbContext` will do the rest automatically for you (change tracking / relationship fixup). That's why an ORM is interesting;

```
protected override void Seed(IQsLab.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
   Album album1 = new Album { /* ... */ };
   Album album2 = new Album { /* ... */ };
   Album album3 = new Album { /* ... */ };

   Song1_1 = new Song { /* ... */ };
   Song1_2 = new Song { /* ... */ };
   Song1_3 = new Song { /* ... */ };

   // ...

   Album1.Songs.Add(Song1_1);
   Album1.Songs.Add(Song1_2);
   Album1.Songs.Add(Song1_3);

   // ...

   context.Albums.Add(Album1);
   context.Albums.Add(Album2);
   context.Albums.Add(Album3);

   // ...

   context.SaveChanges();

 }
```

NOTE 1: the `context.Albums.Add(AlbumN)` method not only attaches the `AlbumN` to the db context, but also all their children. And they all get the state `Added`.

NOTE 2: when you call `SaveChanges` EF takes care to recover the PK of an entity (for example `Album1`) and fix-up the relationships of all related children. In this case that means setting the FK of all the `Song1_*` to the PK recovered when inserting the `Album1`.

By the way, unless you configure it otherwise, the default EF conventions will implement the `int` PKs as identity in the database, so they'll be automatically generated. I'm supposing you've not fine tuned your model with attributes, Fluent API or custom conventions.

So, it's much easier than you expected.